# Swift 3/Alamofire saying failure but it has worked

Tags: php, swift, codeigniter, alamofire

My alamofire request is coming back as a failure when i print the response in xcode however, the web service is actually performing this and everything is supposed to happen as it should apart from the fact its coming back as a failure

```
Alamofire.request(BASE_URL + "index.php/feed/like", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

            let result = response.result

            debugPrint(response)

            print(result)

            if (result.value != nil) {

                let json = JSON(result.value!)

                print(json)

                if json["status"] == false {

                    showError(type: "generic")

                } else {

                    let nolikes = Int(self.lblLikes.text!)! + 1

                    self.lblLikes.text = String(nolikes)

                    self.actionLike.image = UIImage(named: "ActionLiked")

                }

            }

        }
```

this is my error

```
[Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}))
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 509902187.696, "Initial Response Time": 509902188.176, "Request Completed Time": 509902188.177, "Serialization Completed Time": 509902188.177, "Latency": 0.480 secs, "Request Duration": 0.480 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.481 secs }
```

and this is my php function in codeigniter

```
function like_post()
    {

        $post = $this->_post_args;

        $post = $this->security->xss_clean($post);

        $like = $this->Feed_model->likePost($post);

        if($like == TRUE) {

            $this->set_response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'message' => 'SUCCESS'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_ACCEPTED);

        } else {

            $this->set_response([
                    'status' => FALSE,
                    'error' => 'ALREADY_LIKED'
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        }

    }

public function likePost($post)
    {

        $postid = $post['post_id'];
        $userid = $post['user_id'];

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `post_likes` WHERE `user_id` = '{$userid}' AND `post_id` = '{$postid}'");

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            return false;

        } else {

            $insert = [
                'user_id' => $userid,
                'post_id' => $postid
            ];

            $this->db->insert('post_likes', $insert);

            $currpost = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id` = '{$postid}'");
            $likes = $currpost->likes;

            $update = ['likes' => $likes + 1];

            $this->db->update('posts', $update, "post_id = '{$postid}'");

            return true;

        }

    }
```

the code will return false if the user has already performed this action so if i first click on the action it will come back as failure in the console but the php script will run inserting everything to the database etc however, if i click it again i will get the php failure response (so the request shows as successful but it failed)

Comment: Can you also add the response you get from the php code?

Comment: @unkgd i dont get a php response when i first perform the action (i should get the json print saying status = true

if i use postman to perform this, it works as expected so im guessing something is up with my alamofire request

Comment: Yeah, but the request will also fail if there was an error serializing the PHP response, according to the error this is a serialization error: "responseSerializationFailed", so if you'll add the php response maybe we will see if there is a problem there.

Comment: @unkgd the php code is above which shows everything that happens through the function - the like_post performs the likePost() function (this is in the feed model). the likePost function returns either true or false, true then the like_post will send 
`$this->set_response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'message' => 'SUCCESS'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_ACCEPTED);`

Comment: The problem could lie in the PHP response, i.e. the JSON might be displayed incorrectly, either with bad brackets or missing signs, all I need to make sure its not here is a printout of a response, use postman or any other tool to make the request on your end and add the response you receive. Also, did the first request return a successful serialization? or the first one also failed on serialization?

Comment: i did try it on postman and it worked until i switched form pretty view to raw and saw the php error!! thank you for your help!